# ID в БД не прибавляется

Tags: sql, база-данных, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть контроллер который создает новую книгу, и проблема в том что Id у книги не прибавляется и поэтому я не могу создать больше одной книги .

P.S. Primary Key поставил

```
public ActionResult AddBook(Book book)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = string.Format(@"Insert Into [library].[dbo].[Books] 
              (ID, Name, Author, YearOfPublishing) Values(@ID, @Name, @Author, @YearOfPublishing)");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", book.ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", book.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", book.Author);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfPublishing", book.YearOfPublishing);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Book");
    }
```

Я подозреваю в чем проблема ,а именно в этой строке

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", book.ID);
```

По идее идет запись нового ID и если его не указывать то int по дефолту это 0 , поэтому у меня ID постоянно 0

Но если убрать эту строку ,то начнет жаловаться на то что надо убрать и эти параметры

```
ID и @ID
```

окей ,я убрал и это

и теперь я при добавлении получаю ошибку

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'library.dbo.Books'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

то есть невозможно вставить значение NULL в идентификатор столбца

Кто знает как решить эту проблему ?

Если не хватает информации по вопросу пишите - я дополню

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотри здесь https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

надо добавить AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: У меня просто оказался глюк и я пересоздал БД ,но Ваш ответ полезный